# Pushing values from DataView built on one Windows Form to another Windows Form

Tags: c#

I have 2 windows forms. One form with datagridview and button, and the other form with labels. More or less like Master-Detail design. I have 2 related tables in database. I can fill the datagridview nicely with data from the main table. First I select data on datagridview, and I want to use the button to display the values on the labels located on another form.

Once data is loaded on datagridview; I use the following code for the methods to filter the underlying tables based on selection made from datagridview:

```
[form 2]
public DataView EnterpriseView()
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in Viewer.SelectedRows)
            identifier = row.Cells["BusinessName"].Value.ToString();

        var EnterpriseVw = new DataView(EnterpriseDT)
        {
            RowFilter = "BusinessName = '" + identifier + "'"
        };

        return EnterpriseVw;
     }
```

After returning the view, I want to use the button to push the information to another form that has the labels. I'm not sure about how to get this working. I tried different codes of my own, and it doesn't work

My issue how to code the button_click event. And is there another event I need to call for this to work? How does the button know if I have selected something on the datagridview? How does the datagridview know I have clicked the button? I tied something like this for the button:

```
[form 2]
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        index = Viewer.SelectedRows[0].Index;

        Viewer.Rows[index].Selected = true;

        //EnterpriseView();
        //DetailsView();
        //this.Click += new EventHandler(Viewer_SelectionChanged);

        if (Viewer.Rows[index].Selected == true)
        {
            var frm1 = new form1(); //form with labels
            //foreach(DataGridViewRow row in Viewer.SelectedRows)         
            frm1.Publish();  //method that assigns data to labels
        }
```

It doesn't work

I tried using somthing like this for the labels:

```
[form 1]
public void Publish()
    {
        var frm2 = new form2();
        var vEnterprise = frm2.EnterpriseView();

        Email.DataBindings.Add("Text", vEnterprise, "EmailAddress");
}
```

Comment: You can either declare a constructor or some static fields on the second form and pass the details through.

Comment: I believe you mean static fields for assigning values to the labels? Can you provide a code sample? What about coding the button click event?

Comment: Isn't the problem passing values from one form to another ?

Comment: Just edited to show the form names, how I laid out the code now. So that if I'm doing something wrong you can easily assist

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa. Thanx. I'll try using the static fields.

Comment: Can someone also simplify the solution? or provide another solution can I can follow?

Answer (score 0):

To Get values from Selected Row of the DataGridView you need to change some properties :

**First** You need to set `SelectionMode` to `FullRowSelect`.

**Second** You need to set `MultiSelect` to `False`.

You can do it through the properties tab.

Then we can use `dataGridView1.SelectedRows` it will return `DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection` a list of the selected rows, but since we disabled multiSelect there will always be just one so we can use `[0]`.

Now in the Button_click event Handler

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
   // To Get The Selected Row
   var  dr =  dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];

   // The Cells Property is going to return DataGridViewCellCollection a list again
   // Basically the columns so the first one will be the first column and so on
   string item1 = dr.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
   string item2 = dr.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
   string item3 = dr.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
}
```

---

In the Form with the labels Define a second constructor.

Say we Have 3 Labels

We gonna define a second constructor that takes 3 Strings, Like this

```
public TheSecondForm(String S1, String S2,String S3) 
{
    label1.Text = S1;
    label2.Text = S2;
    label3.Text = S3;         
}
```

Then The button Event Handle will become like this :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
   var  dr =  dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];

   string item1 = dr.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
   string item2 = dr.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
   string item3 = dr.Cells[2].Value.ToString();

   // What was added
   TheSecondForm frm2 = new TheSecondForm(item1, item2, item3);
   frm2.Show();
}
```

By Now the labels will be populated.

Comment: Thanx. I get the idea. Will let you know if I manage to resolve the issue. Can you assist with the button_click event. Help with selecting a row on datagridview using a button. First I use the arrows to highlight row, then click button to use the row for code execution. How do I use this higlighted row or selected row from button click event?

Comment: I don't fully get what you want, is it that you want to select a row then click a button then all the information from that row get passed to the other form ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. I get the idea of the constructor and the static fields. But I need assistance in coding the button click event to know or be aware that I have highlighted a row in datagridview. After I highlight or select row in datagridview using arrows, how do interact with that particular row? My code shown above for the button click event doesnt work. I get an empty result from the dataview constructed. There's something I'm not doing right there with interacting with the row. I get System.IndexOfRangeException (index 0 is either negative or above rows count)

Comment: The datagridview is populated. But when I use the button with the code above to test constructing the DataView after filtering the datatable (using the EnterpriseView method), I get an empty DataView ! I believe the issue is with the selection code in button click event. Assist with resolving here